# Linked resource dictionary and StaticResource reference at root level

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534611/setting-a-style-to-a-static-resource-for-a-root-control-element), which doesn't apply to my case, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371100/use-staticresource-in-xaml-root-element), which I'm not sure whether it can be adapted.

I'm working on a WPF control library, and I don't have an App.xaml file. I use a file called **Styles.xml** to store common brushes and other resources. In the XAML file of my user control I import the resources and then I try to use brush **sBrush** as a background.

This works except that at the root level:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMControls.TitledWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=sBrush}"> <!--EXCEPTION!-->

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                 Source="pack://application:,,,/CMControls;component/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Canvas Background="{StaticResource ResourceKey=sBrush}" ... <!--Ok.-->
...
```

I presume this happens because when the root element is instantiated its children are not, including **UserControl.Resources**. Is there any workaround? **Note that in the designer everything works fine, no matter where I make the reference**.

Comment: are you using themes/generic.xaml ?

Comment: No, I'm not. Thank you for your comment, I may give it a look, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `UserControl` Background after Resource Merging line,because you have to add resources before using them!

```
 <UserControl x:Class="CMControls.TitledWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
             Source="pack://application:,,,/CMControls;component/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
 <UserControl.Background>  <!--Set background here!-->
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="sBrush"></StaticResource> 
 </UserControl.Background>
 ...
```

Comment: Nice, thank you :-) I heard that you can use elements and attributes to set the same properties but I wasn't sure about the syntax.